# React Native TouchableNativeFeedback

Tags: react-native

Using React-Native has a long press error

Using TouchableHighlight And TouchableNativeFeedback

Attempted to transition from state `RESPONDER_INACTIVE_PRESS_IN` to `RESPONDER_ACTIVE_LONG_PRESS_IN`

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cnpt.png)

Comment: whats your trying code?

Comment: Sorry,I forgot.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cnpt.png

Comment: plz edit your question and add your code to question

Comment: Well, I've edited my question

Answer (score 12):

This issue usually only appears in android when you are debugging.
This issue https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5823 goes into further detail.

Try turning debugging off and see if you still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Aligning the clocks on your phone and computer may solve this problem. My experience is that the two clocks do not need to be exact match, just make sure they are not off by more than a few seconds. You can easily achieve this by adjusting one clock manually.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the same issue I faced it, after a much more research I found its's solution that instead of using TouchableHighlight, you can use TouchableOpacity component .
For detail refer this link -

http://androidseekho.com/others/reactnative/how-to-solve-touchable-longpressdelaytimeout-problem-in-react-native/